# command works in the terminal, wont work in php

Tags: php

I've made an extension for my web application in php. I want the php script to remake the extension, so I'm trying to send a command to the terminal. It looks like this:

```
shell_exec("make -C /folder1/folder2");
```

And it won't make the .so file no matter what. I've used `chmod 777` on that folder to make it editable but it didn't help. When I'm directly using the command in the terminal it works just fine:

```
make -C /folder1/folder2
```

The .so file gets created without a problem, functions from my extension work like they should. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Try putting the absolute path to `make` in the PHP script, e.g. `/usr/bin/make`.

Comment: tried it just now, still the same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that PHP is not running in safe mode and that the PHP user has read/write access to the files and folders. Read the comments at [shell-exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) for more information.

Comment: safe mode is off, and i can freely manually edit/add/delete the files in that folder

Comment: You can, but can the user that apache/PHP runs as?

Comment: Linux by default has a lot more users than that, but the rest usually don't have login access. Apache tends to run as apache, http, www-user, or something similar. Check top or `ps aux | grep httpd` to find out the user that apache is running as, and make sure that the files and folders you're trying to access are set to readable by that user, either by adding the apache user to the group, or (a really bad idea, but will work) set the files and directory to 777.

Comment: i just used "whoami" in the php script and man you're right. It returned .www-data . :) I'm pretty new to linux, is there an easy way to just add permissions for that user?

Comment: If that folder is only going to be used by apache, then chown that folder to www-data. You'll just need the group that www-data belongs to. Then do `chown -R owner:group folder`

Comment: You might want to check over on http://superuser.com/ to find out how to get those files/folders usable by www-data.